# How to get the position of a typed letter in a textarea with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a dropdown while typing in a textarea. How can I get the position of the typed letter given a keyup event?

Comment: https://github.com/component/textarea-caret-position

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by position? Like the x and y coordinates of the character itself? Or the index of the character in the string in the textarea?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the x and y coordinates on the screen, so I can position the dropdown in the right place.

Comment: That's tricky! I suggest you to use the attribute contenteditable instead of using an textarea. Using a div with contentediable you can wrap the last typed character into a span and get its offsetTop and offsetLeft to place your dropdown

Answer (score 2):

Greg's answer seems to work. But if you want a more simpler way to get it, you can access the `selectionStart` property of the textarea.

For example

```
var myTextArea = $("#mytextarea");

myTextArea.keyup(function () {

   console.log("The last typed character is at: ", myTextArea.get(0).selectionStart - 1);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wasjdhtu/

Answer (score 1):

```
var oldValue = '';
var keyup = function() {
    var value = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
    for(var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
        if(i >= oldValue.length) {
            // letter typed at end
            oldValue = value;
            return; // not really necessary since we should be at the end of the loop anyway
        } else if(value.charAt(i) !== oldValue.charAt(i)) {
            // letter typed at i
            oldValue = value;
            return; // no need to keep searching
        }
    }
    // no new letters typed
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant the x and y coordinates on the screen, so I can position the dropdown in the right place.

Comment: Ah that's tricky. You'd need the pixel width of each character in the font you're using, and you'd likely run into problems across different browsers. I'd seriously consider doing something simpler. Most people just align the dropdown with the input box.

Comment: You could also try using something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript